# React router Dom Link does not change URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my `Index.js` file:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Routes } from "react-router-dom";


import Projects from "./Pages/Projects";
import Experience from "./Pages/Experience";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route exact path="/Experience" element={<Experience />} />
      <Route exact path="/Projects" element={<Projects />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

This is how I am trying to change the link:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Eliptical from "./Eliptical";
import { Html } from "@react-three/drei";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


export default function Planet({ planet: { color, xRadius, zRadius, size, speed, offset,Name = ""} }) {
   ...
  
    return (
      <>
        <mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={(e) => {
          <Link to="/Projects"></Link>
```

The issue is It registers the click but does not redirect the page. The pages are setup so when I access "url.com/Experience" it does render but I cant change url when I click.

Comment: what is mesh in this?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/7092628

Comment: Its a three js object works like a normal link i think

Answer (score 0):

You can't call JSX in an event handler like this and expect it to do anything. In your case you should use the `useNavigate` hook and issue an imperative navigation.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Planet({ planet: { color, xRadius, zRadius, size, speed, offset,Name = ""} }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  ...
  
  return (
    <>
      <mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={(e) => {
        navigate("/Projects");
```

Comment: I get a new error : useNavigate() may only be used in the context of a Router component

Comment: @cutecucumber Oh, sorry, just now saw your comment. That error says you are not rendering this `Planet` component within a routing context, in other words, it isn't rendered as a descendent of a `Router` component.

Comment: @cutecucumber Has this answer helped answer/resolve your question/issue?